# Should I still be paid for my expenses?

Tags: salary, expenses

We are required to enter our expenses (and time) into an online system. Last Friday I had about $150 worth of expenses for travel that day. Apparently, our accountant said that the expenses were not entered and she tried to contact me by email several times to get them entered before the cut off day (yesterday).

I know that I entered my expenses and double checked. When I checked today, they were gone. This system is known to have issues with deleting data that's been entered into it. The accountant is saying that the company isn't responsible for paying the expenses because they weren't there.

Our handbook only says that "expenses are paid at the discretion of the company". How can I make sure that I get reimbursed for my business expenses? $150 is a decent chunk of money to lose out on.

Comment: Can you clarify more? Is the accountant saying they are never going to reimburse you or that they will reimburse you only when it is entered into the system?

Comment: I can understand getting in expenses before a deadline in order to be included in a particular pay period, but never have I heard of expenses not being paid if not entered before a deadline.  Two things: 1) You still have proof of expense? 2) Where are you?

Comment: Since the system loses expenses, in the future CYA. Print a copy of the screen that shows the entered expenses.

Comment: Do you have to send receipts?

Comment: Policies like this are terrible, but common. They create an antagonistic relationship between employees and the company. If you travel regularly, request a company credit card so you're not going out of pocket.

Comment: "*How can I make sure that I get reimbursed for my business expenses*" Enter them again? Putting this on hold pending clarification from the OP as to what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely push for the reimbursement.

"At the discretion of the company" is likely just there to make it easier to deny someone claiming exorbitant expenses (like a business lunch at a 5 star restaurant).

Answer (score 5):

There's the issue right there

> This system is known to have issues with deleting data that's been entered into it

So, follow the same workflow as other people who have also lost their expenses.  Ask around, see who else was affected and follow their advice here.

Plus, you have your receipts and mileage details, so you should be able to ask your manager if you can re-submit these since the amount and date of reimbursement will be known (i.e. it will be simple to prove you're not defrauding the expenses system by claiming for the same thing twice).